# Modules in gradle from git using VPN in android

Tags: android, git

I need create modules for my app, where modules will be created on git and connection is only using VPN. How can I add this modules to my project?
I tried add:

```
  maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
```

and `compile "http://192.168.10.10/edi/module:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT"`
but I got error: `"Could not find:http://192.168.10.10/edi/module:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT""`
any ideas?